# Python: find line == x in file

Tags: python, file, hash, md5

Just for the sake of practice, I'm making an md5 decoder (encode something, and it's hash is added to the database). For this, I'm going to have an encrypter that saves the text and the hash to their own files, one encryption/decryption on each line. So, how would I look for a line that is equal to x in theFile?

Comment: Why not use a database tool like SQLite? If you're just a little familiar with SQL this should be easy to search, and you could also use LIKE (as far as i know) to make wildcard searches.

Comment: You mean `for line in theFile: if line==x: do_something(line)`?

Comment: What you could do, is use shelves.. Which is like using a filesystem as a dictionary. If you create the hash and the solution and store them in a dictionary.. You could store that dictionary on a shelf.

Comment: @Bry6n or pickle for that matter. But if the feature for wildcards is needed, I would think that SQLite still is the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply open it, read a line and compare it

```
fp = open("file")
for i, line in enumerate(fp):
  if line == x
    do something
fp.close()
```

Comment: But note that the lines from `fp` will have a trailing newline, so if `x` doesn't have that, the comparison will fail.

Answer (score 1):

Are you implying the use of some advanced procedure or a simple statement like:

```
with open("myfile.txt") as file:
    for line in file.readlines():
        if line == x:
            # do something
```

will work for you?

Comment: @Bry6n how would you describe it, if not Python?

Comment: Nevermind. Read this quickly on my Android. The syntax looked off.